# Why exclude the last group element when picking Elgamal secret key

Tags: elgamal-encryption, group-theory

Christof Paar explains in [his lectures](https://youtu.be/tKNY1zhK3sQ?si=3MY88yYucRXK7I38&t=1683) that Elgamal encryption scheme picks the private key from $\{2, \ldots, p-2\}$, is there a reason for excluding the last and first elements?

Comment: they are 1 and -1, does this make sense?

Comment: Oh, I see, could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: Your public key is easily recognizable, however, what is the probability of getting 1 or -1 from uniform random? Why not to exclude 2,3,4, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElGamal's encryption scheme works with the private key any integer $d$ (including negative).

However $d$ only matters modulo $\lambda(p)$ (the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)), which is modulo $p-1$ for prime $p$ as in Christof Paar's presentation. This is a good reason to exclude any $d$ larger then $p-2$, or negative: they would work as $d'=d\bmod(p-1)$, with thus $0\le d'\le p-2$, leading to (typically) simpler calculation than with the larger or negative $d$.

Excluding $d=0$ (and the equivalent $d=p-1$) is probably because the ciphertext would always consist of the constant $1$ and the plaintext, which is less than satisfactory from an encryption perspective. Excluding $d=1$ is probably because it makes the public key recognizable as the parameter $\alpha$.

We could similarly argue that we must exclude $d=p-2$, because it makes the public key recognizable as $p-\alpha$. Or $d=2$, which makes the public key $\alpha^2\bmod p$. Or any $d$ smaller than $10^{20}$, because we can recover $d$ with like $10^{10}$ modular multiplications, which is easy on a single PC.

But such exclusions are pointless theoretically, and practically for $p$ large enough to give security (that is $p$ of many hundred bits; 795 bit is [breakable with academic means](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/697)): the probability that any of the excluded $d$ gets used as the public key is negligible.

The set $\{2,p-2\}$ in Christof Paar's presentation makes sense for small $p$ that are often used as example, as it avoids any special case that might raise question. The theorist would probably prefer  $\{0,p-2\}$ or $\{1,p-1\}$ (the later avoids questions about what $\alpha^0$ is).